# d3 set number of gradation for color scales

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I made a color scale like this:

```
var clr = d3.scale.linear()
   .range(["white',"black"])
   .domain(...)

var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(clr.ticks(9))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
```

is there a way to specify the number of color scales? I'm updating the chart with different datasets, and currently each time i update the number of scales changes.

Comment: What do you mean by *"the number of color scales"*? There is just one colour scale in your question, which is `cir`. Please explain what's your actual goal.

Comment: sorry i meant gradation. I tried to do a ordinal scale but not sure how to display the value cutoff of each gradation

Comment: So, all you want is just an array of 9 colours going from white to black, is that correct?

Comment: yes, i also did something like clr.ticks(9).slice(1), but still not working perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to create an array of colours with a given number of steps. Keeping you linear scale, this is one of them:

```js
var clr = d3.scale.linear()
  .range(["white", "black"])
  .domain([0, 8]);

var colourArray = d3.range(9).map(function(d) {
  return clr(d)
});;

console.log(colourArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Here, we create 9 colours, going from `white` to `black`. The basic idea is setting a domain (`[0, 8]`) and, using an array with 9 numbers going from the start to the end of that domain (`d3.range(9)`), populate the array with `map`.

Here is a demo showing the colours:

```js
var clr = d3.scale.linear()
  .range(["white", "black"])
  .domain([0, 8]);

var colourArray = d3.range(9).map(function(d) {
  return clr(d)
});

var divs = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(9))
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", function(d, i) {
    return colourArray[i]
  })
```

```css
div {
  min-width: 30px;
  min-height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what if my domain depends on the data. I have .domain([0, d3.max()]), is it possible to dynamically split into 9 colours?

Comment: Yes, just use `d3.range` with the start, the stop and the steps. Have in mind that, as you asked in the comments, I just created an array of colours: you can easily access it with the index, without any data. However, I have a strong feeling that, in your case, you couls use a quantile scale: https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Quantitative-Scales.md#quantile It's hard to say since I don't know what are you doing.

Comment: i'm trying to change the color of some data based on its value. So i have var block = svg.selectAll().style("fill", function(d){return clr(d.value)}); it currently uses 5 as an increment, so 0-5 is one color and 5-10 is another.

Comment: So, in your case, use a quantile scale. Have a look at the API to understand how to use it.